# Suffix Field Values based on number of occurrences in Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a table in  MS Access that has a field `layout_desc`. I need to create a query that changes each value in this field by adding how many times the value is repeated in the table.

For example:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Without a primary key:

Assuming that your table does **not** contain a primary key field by which to sort records using a domain aggregate function, one possible method is using Static variables in VBA.

- Open the VBA IDE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Insert a new Public Module <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>
- Copy the following basic code into the new Module:

  ```vb
  Function Occurrence(Optional strVal As String) As Long
      Static lngTmp As Long
      Static strTmp As String
      If strTmp = strVal Then
          lngTmp = lngTmp + 1
      Else
          lngTmp = 1
          strTmp = strVal
      End If
      Occurrence = lngTmp
  End Function
  ```
- In MS Access, create a new query with the following SQL, changing `YourTable` to the name of your table:

  ```sql
  update (select t.layout_desc from YourTable as t order by t.layout_desc) q
  set q.layout_desc = q.layout_desc & occurrence(q.layout_desc)
  ```

#### With a primary key:

If your table were to include a primary key, say `id`, of Long Integer data type, you could use the domain aggregate function `DCount` in the following way:

```sql
update YourTable t
set t.layout_desc = t.layout_desc & 
dcount("*","YourTable","layout_desc = '" & t.layout_desc & "' and id <= " & t.id)
```

Comment: @ali You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!